# How the track the usage of settings in appsettings.json file

Tags: azure, .net-core

I have a complex ASP.NET Core application which has 100's of values in the `appsettings.json` file. The values are composed from dozens of sections which gets deserialized into C# objects at startup.

Many of these settings were added 3 years and are unused. Is there way to track which of these appsettings are used by the application at runtime?

I am open to use Azure services such as appinsights or Azure App Configuration if it helps.

Comment: You can set the appsettings in `Configuration` section in Azure Web App.It overrides the values from `appsettings.json`. You can set only the settings which you are sure and feel it is required.

Answer (score 0):

- We can use `Azure Application settings`, App settings can change configuration values based on the environment.
- Application Settings in Azure overrides the values from `appsettings.json`.
- We need to add the app/connection string settings in Azure web App with the same name as the settings mentioned in local appsettings or `web.config files`, then only values will be overidden
- If we don't specify any app settings in Azure, it reads the local `appsettings.json` values by default

[image]

Please refer [Configure app settings in Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-common?tabs=portal#configure-app-settings)  and [Environment variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#environment-variables)

Comment: This information does not answer the question. The question is about tracking the usage of this settings at runtime